# How to download all sheets in a google sheet in R

Tags: r, google-sheets, download

I'm looking to download all of the sheets in a single google sheet in R.
I'm currently using the `gsheet` package by `[maxconway][1]`, which allows me to download a sheet using its URL, but it only works on individual sheets, which are differentiated by a `gid`.
The set of google sheets I'm trying to download has over 100 sheets, which makes downloading them one by one with `gsheet` massively inconvenient - does anyone know of any R packages that automate this or of any way to loop through all of the sheets in a single google sheet?

Here is the code I currently have which downloads just the first of over 100 sheets as a tibble:

```
all_rolls <- gsheet2tbl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OEg29XbL_YpO0m5JrLQpOPYTnxVsIg8iP67EYUrtRJg/edit#gid=26346344')

> head(all_rolls)
# A tibble: 6 x 14
  Episode Time   Character `Type of Roll` `Total Value` `Natural Value` `Crit?` `Damage Dealt` `# Kills`
    <int> <drtn> <chr>     <chr>          <chr>         <chr>           <chr>   <chr>              <int>
1       1 37'53" Vex'ahlia Intelligence   20            18              <NA>    <NA>                  NA
2       1 41'48" Grog      Persuasion     19            18              <NA>    <NA>                  NA
3       1 43'25" Keyleth   Persuasion     2             2               <NA>    <NA>                  NA
4       1 46'35" Tiberius  Persuasion     12            3               <NA>    <NA>                  NA
5       1 46'35" Tiberius  Persuasion     27            18              <NA>    <NA>                  NA
6       1 46'35" Percy     Assist         21            15              <NA>    <NA>                  NA
# … with 5 more variables: Notes <chr>, `Non-Roll Kills` <chr>, X12 <chr>, X13 <chr>, X14 <chr>
```

Note: I've tried removing the `#gid` field, but then it just downloads the first sheet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE 2021-01-31**: updated code to use new functions that replaced `sheets_find()` and `sheets_sheets()` as of `googlesheets4` version 0.2.0.

The `googlesheets4` package includes a function to list all sheets associated with an account's Google Drive: `sheets_find()`. From the list of sheets one can use the sheet IDs to read the sheets into R.

```
library(googlesheets4)
sheets_auth()
theSheets <- gs4_find()
theSheets
```

My test account on Google has one Google sheet, a spreadsheet of Pokémon Stats.

```
> theSheets
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  name         id                                           drive_resource   
* <chr>        <chr>                                        <list>           
1 PokemonStats 13rGxY7ScDUl7bFJ9NipO7QUafEACYTH4MagFjcj4pVw <named list [34]>
```

We can use the ID field to download the sheet.

```
pokemonData <- sheets_read(theSheets$id[1])
head(pokemonData)


> head(pokemonData)
# A tibble: 6 x 13
  Number Name  Type1 Type2 Total    HP Attack Defense SpecialAtk SpecialDef Speed
   <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl>
1      1 Bulb… Grass Pois…   318    45     49      49         65         65    45
2      2 Ivys… Grass Pois…   405    60     62      63         80         80    60
3      3 Venu… Grass Pois…   525    80     82      83        100        100    80
4      3 Venu… Grass Pois…   625    80    100     123        122        120    80
5      4 Char… Fire  NA      309    39     52      43         60         50    65
6      5 Char… Fire  NA      405    58     64      58         80         65    80
# … with 2 more variables: Generation <dbl>, Legendary <lgl>
>
```

One could use the vector `theSheets$id` with `lapply()` to read a group of sheets from Google Drive as follows:

```
sheetList <- lapply(theSheets$id,sheet_read)
```

To read multiple worksheets within a Google Sheets spreadsheet, we add the `sheet=` argument to `sheet_read()`. Here we read the Pokémon Types from the second worksheet in the Pokémon Stats spreadsheet.

```
pokemonTypes <- sheets_read(theSheets$id[1],sheet = 2)
head(pokemonTypes)
```

...and the output:

```
> head(pokemonTypes)
# A tibble: 6 x 1
  Type    
  <chr>   
1 Fire    
2 Grass   
3 Poison  
4 Water   
5 Bug     
6 Fighting
>
```

### Reading all worksheets in a spreadsheet

We can automate the process of reading multiple tabs from a single spreadsheet. The `sheets_sheets()` function is useful for this purpose.

```
# technique where we read multiple worksheets by worksheet name
# using functions from googlesheets4 version 0.2.0. 
theSheets <-gs4_find()
# get metadata from first sheet
sheetMetadata <- gs4_get(theSheets$id[1])
# get worksheet tab names
sheetNames <- sheet_names(theSheets$id[1])
sheetNames
```

At this point we can see that there are two worksheet tabs in the Pokémon Stats spreadsheet. We use the vector `sheetNames` with `lapply()` to read all the worksheets within the main spreadsheet.

```
theWorksheets <- lapply(sheetNames, function(x){             
     sheets_read(theSheets$id[1],sheet = x) 
})
# use the `names()` function to name the data frames stored in the list
names(theWorksheets) <- sheetNames
lapply(theWorksheets,head)
```

...and the output:

```
> lapply(theWorksheets,head)
$Pokemon
# A tibble: 6 x 13
  Number Name  Type1 Type2 Total    HP Attack Defense SpecialAtk SpecialDef Speed
   <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl>
1      1 Bulb… Grass Pois…   318    45     49      49         65         65    45
2      2 Ivys… Grass Pois…   405    60     62      63         80         80    60
3      3 Venu… Grass Pois…   525    80     82      83        100        100    80
4      3 Venu… Grass Pois…   625    80    100     123        122        120    80
5      4 Char… Fire  NA      309    39     52      43         60         50    65
6      5 Char… Fire  NA      405    58     64      58         80         65    80
# … with 2 more variables: Generation <dbl>, Legendary <lgl>

$Metadata
# A tibble: 6 x 1
  Type    
  <chr>   
1 Fire    
2 Grass   
3 Poison  
4 Water   
5 Bug     
6 Fighting

>
```

At this point individual worksheets can be accessed with the `$` form of the extract operator, as `theWorksheets$Pokemon` or `theWorksheets$Metadata`.

Comment: Thank you! However, I'm hoping to use this to read from a public view-only Google Sheet not on my account. For context, I'm making a package that automatically downloads and cleans data from this website: https://www.critrolestats.com/stats-vm. Much of the data is in public google sheet form, but I don't want users to have to authenticate or have these sheets in their drive to use it.
I tried to use the `gs4_deauth()` function in the package, but that just spat out `Error: could not find function "gs4_auth"`. Would you happen to know a workaround?

Comment: Never mind - it seems R was out of date on my laptop, leading to errors. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: Since sheets_sheets() is deprecated I can't make this work, any workarounds?

Comment: @MarcioRodrigues - the deprecated code still works (for now), but it generates warning messages.  Also, the warning messages provide the names of the functions that replaced `sheets_sheets()` and `sheets_get()`. I will update my answer to include the new functions, `sheet_names()` and `gs4_get()`.

Comment: Hello @mkane, I have learnt a lot from this post. But I can't figure out a way around the authentication and I don't want users to have to authenticate using my account. Please help me with your solutions. Thank you

Comment: I solved it using the function gs4_deauth() nd it worked. Ref: https://googlesheets4.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/auth.html Thank you

Answer (score 1):

## Use R programming to import all Google Sheets sheets.

The `read_gsheets()` function in `bulkreadr` package imports data from multiple sheets in a Google Sheets spreadsheet and appends the resulting dataframes from each sheet together to create a single dataframe. This function is a powerful tool for data analysis, as it allows you to easily combine data from multiple sheets into a single dataset.

```
# Load packages

library(bulkreadr)

link_to_Gsheets <- "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1szpcXG9m3jgFAhXjM3qhOg-YpXvRW3T08u8-urXz2Oo"

diamonds <- read_gsheets(ss = link_to_Gsheets, .id = "Cuts")
```

[image]

**Explanation of codes:**

ss:  Something that identifies a Google Sheet:

- its file id as a string or drive_id
- a URL from which we can recover the id

.id: The name of an optional identifier column. Provide a string to create an output column that identifies each input. The column will use names if available, otherwise it will use positions.